# Aspectj : deploying aspects in an existing web application

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, ejb-3.0, aspectj

I am working on an existing web application that uses EJB3. What I need to do is to weave some aspects into this application, in order to log some information after matching some specific methods (before and after persisting beans).

I am deploying my web application in a Jboss server in an ear format. the ear contains a war (servlets) and a jar (session beans and entity beans).

Any idea on how is this possible ? Do I have to put my aspects inside the jar or do I have to create a new jar (exclusively for aspects) ?

By the way I am using eclipse for this project. So my jar corresponds to an EJB project and my war corresponds to a dynamic web project.

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know for web-apps it's only possible to do so with load-time weaving (shouldn't be mixed with compile-time one, they are not compatible with each other). To achieve that you should do the following:

- Create `aop.xml` ([link](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/pdguide/ltwdump.html) to the documentation how to do that) and put it into the `META-INF` folder of your project.
- add `aspectjweaver/tools/rt` jars to your dependencies.
- disable compile-time weaving (That's a configuration in your pom.xml. Read more [there](http://tech.kovacs-telekes.org/content/enabling-load-time-weaving-tomcat))
- add to your app-server's `JVM` the following argument `-javaagent:pathto/aspectjweaver.jar` ([documentation](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/devguide/ltw-agents.html))
- add the `aspectjweaver.jar` to your server's resources

That's it.

You should disable compile-time weaving im your pom.xml (if you use maven, of course). Unfortunately I didn't try to do that without maven (solely with `Eclipse AspectJ` plugin). Here is how it will probably look like.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- disabling -->
                    <outxml>true</outxml>
                    <XterminateAfterCompilation>true</XterminateAfterCompilation>
                    <!-- disabling -->
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have any idea on how to disable compile-time weaving in eclipse ?

Comment: Just put your aspects into their own project and you do not need to care about premature weaving because the aspects are separated from the application code. You can just create a separate JAR from your aspects and flexibly deploy them whenever you need them. If you do not deploy them, no LTW will happen either. Piece of cake. ;-)

Comment: BTW, it is not true that web apps are "incompatible with CTW" in any way. As long as *aspectjrt.jar* is on the classpath, it works.

Comment: @kriegaex I tried to go with CTW first, but couldn't configure it. I didn't claim that it's impossible, no :). In a desktop application it's easy to do, but in a web....

Comment: In case you wondering why yours not working. Make sure you have this plugin compiling the aspect/class - https://www.mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/index.html. It worked for me.